# How to compare two arrays and get unique values

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays, I need to compare them and get unique values ​​from the second array only.

Example:

```
array_first = [1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11] # Array for comparison
array_last = [1,2,6,4,7,5,12] # The array from which you want to get values ​​that are not in the other

res: [6,7,12] # The values ​​to get
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`Array#-`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Array.html#method-i-2D)

```
array_first = [1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11]
array_last = [1,2,6,4,7,5,12]

array_last - array_first
#=> [6, 7, 12]
```

Quote from the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Array.html#method-i-2D):

> `array - other_array` → `new_array`
>
> Returns a new Array containing only those elements from `array` that are not found in Array `other_array`; items are compared using `eql?` [...]